# rails attaching database entry to logged in user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm new to rails and am done setting up my login system. However, I want someone to be able to make a new blog post and attach it to their account when logged in. How can I attach a post to their user_id as well as list all their previous posts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a model posts ( should have column name user_id )

```
model Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

In user Model

```
model User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
end
```

With the above defined associations user_id will be a foriegn key to User model so you can
get all posts by user something like below

```
 User.find(id).posts
```

Comment: If I'm using devise, should I be using the `current_user` helper somewhere in the post_controller or post model? I guess what I'm asking is -- since I'm using a controller OUTSIDE of the user_controller, is there some way I need to specify the current session or user somewhere?

Comment: I am not sure about devise but as you mentioned if you have current_user or any specific user you can do @user.posts

Comment: I have a helper that gives you the current logged in user (that helper is current_user). When I add belongs_to :user and has_many :posts it doesn't seem to be grabbing the id of the user and throwing into the user_id column of the post. So I guess I'm wondering if there's anything else I need to do to get it to see that it needs to take the current user's id

Comment: Did not get what you are asking can you be more specific

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few different approaches, but John Nunemaker's user_stamp gem is pretty straightforward and simple to get running.

https://github.com/jnunemaker/user_stamp

Just add a creator_id and updater_id to your table, a single line in your ApplicationController, and it'll do the rest!

Answer (score 0):

You can associate models with each other by following this guide on [rails associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html). One solution for you might be:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
end
```

You just have to make sure that your posts table has a column called user_id. Assuming your user table is called users. this will set up a one to many association between users and posts. From a User instance you will be able to do user.posts and get a list of the associated posts for that user.

The guide is much better at explaining this stuff and it's worth your while to read the whole thing--even the parts you don't need right now.

Comment: You forgot `belongs_to :user`

Comment: the guide says it is often used but they don't explicitly say it's required.. It doesn't clarify what cases you wouldn't use it for though.

Comment: I guess if you only need `user.posts`, you don't need it, but if you want to use `post.user` you do.

Comment: yeah. And it admittedly feels kind of silly, in the context of the OP question, not to be able to use post.user :P

Comment: If I'm using devise, should I be using the `current_user` helper somewhere in the post_controller or post model? I guess what I'm asking is -- since I'm using a controller OUTSIDE of the user_controller, is there some way I need to specify the current session or user somewhere?